# Appium Inspector is unable to find the locator of some UI component for IOS

Tags: iphone, accessibility, ios-simulator, webdriver-io, appium-ios

I am trying do e2e on my ios APP using webdriverIO and Appium.

When I am inspecting the element of some UI Component from appium-inspector, the whole screen is getting hovered/inspected and because of this, proper XML is not gettting generated.

Just FYI: The id/label is already given for the layout.

I tried by even giving some key like- accessible={false} but no luck!

[image]